# Thymeleaf removes type="text" from input element

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

My template is: `<input type="text" name="foo" />`

What thymeleaf is doing: `<input name="foo" />`

This works:
`<input th:type="text" name="foo" />` gets `<input type="text" name="foo" />`

... as well as that: `<input type="submit" name="foo" />` gets `<input type="submit" name="foo" />`

I do not know, why thymeleaf is doing that (maybe because of "text" is the default type for an input). 
Since because of that behavior the CSS does not fit anymore.

My configuration:

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    check-template-location: true
    prefix: classpath:/templates/
    suffix: .html
    mode: HTML5
    encoding: UTF-8
    content-type: text/html
    cache: false
```

There is no use of `th:remove` in my code. Any other ideas?

Thanks for helping! :-)

Comment: kindly post the full themeleaf content in your page.

Comment: I don't think, that it helps. But okay:

    `<div class="panel">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label for="user-description" class="control-label" th:text="#{user-description.label}"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="user-description" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`

As you can see, I work with templates (loaded by angular).